# Gem is installed but fails when rails server starts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, bcrypt

I have a problem with the bcrypt gem. I ran this:

```
gem install bcrypt
```

and got:

```
Fetching: bcrypt-3.1.10-x64-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bcrypt-3.1.10-x64-mingw32
Parsing documentation for bcrypt-3.1.10-x64-mingw32
Installing ri documentation for bcrypt-3.1.10-x64-mingw32
Done installing documentation for bcrypt after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

I can see the installed gem in the list:

```
bcrypt (3.1.10 x64-mingw32)
```

When I start Rails:

```
rails server
```

I got an error (I am pasting just a header to keep it clean):

```
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.10-x64-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
```

I use Windows and Ruby 2.2. DevKit is installed. Environment variables are set:

- `PATH`: `C:\Ruby\devkit\mingw\bin;C:\Ruby\devkit\bin`
- `RI_DEVKIT`: `C:\Ruby\devkit`

In order to validate it I ran:

```
make --version
```

and got:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i686-pc-msys
```

which seems fine to me.

A similar issue occurs with Nokogiri.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research and I've got an answer:

`gem install` detects the Ruby platform. Then it automatically creates the name of the gem which finally looks like this:

```
bcrypt-3.1.10-x64-mingw32
```

This gem is supposed to have a pre-compiled version for this particular platform, but, for Ruby 2.2, there is no compiled bcrypt_ext.so. 2.1 is the last version supported which leads to the problem. In this case there are two solutions:

1. The gem simply needs to be recompiled using DevKit:

   ```
   gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby
   ```

   which will compile sources and create required bcrypt_ext.so.
2. Downgrade Ruby to 2.1.

The same logic is for Nokogiri.

I hope it helps someone.